# Who are the three illusionists that have deceived Vindice?

Tags: reborn

After re-reading **Katekyou Hitman Reborn!** for like the twentieth time, I noticed something that wasn't really explained.

**Chapter 264**

[image: Image In Question]

Who are the three illusionists?

Runner-Ups

- Flan
- Viper/Mammon
- Mukuro
- Daemon
- Kawahira/CheckerFace
- Chrome (Maybe)

Comment: I knew about the Wiki post but I felt there was inconsistency and a Wiki post is made mostly on facts but not entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The illusionists that could actually pull it are:

- Mukuro
- Flan
- Daemon
- Kawahira
- Viper
- Tyl Chrome (Probably)

For starters, they didn't count Flan. Flan was unknown generally. He was Mukuro's trump card and that worked on both Vindice and Byakuran.

Next, they said, "in this world". That part is very important. Viper and Daemon are not of that world. Viper was dead and I'm guessing Daemon was dealt with or was never known to Vindice.

So the remaining ones are:

- Mukuro
- Kawahira
- Chrome

Answer (score 0):

- Flan
- Mukuro
- Viper (released form) (not sure)

You can read more from: [Vindice](http://reborn.wikia.com/wiki/Vindice) and [Illusions](http://reborn.wikia.com/wiki/Illusions)

> Only three illusionists have the power to fool the Vindice; Flan and Mukuro Rokudo are two of the known three; however Viper, in his released form, has shown that he too is capable of using illusions powerful enough to fool the Vindice, though it was stated that the trick would not work a second time.

Comment: I get what you mean. I am assuming that during that chapter they did not include Flan, because when Iris mentioned they were done in by Vongola's illusionists, Vindice should have known Flan was in Vongola but sounded shocked.